# Objects not initialized

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

in objective C, I can do the following

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPhoto.jpg"];
variable.image = myImage;
```

and this works just fine. but the object named "myImage" was never initialized, and the UIImage never had any memory allocated and yet the code still works..

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the object was initialised.  The `imageNamed:` method allocates and initialises an object, sends it an `autorelease` message, then returns the memory address to you.  You store that memory address in the pointer called `myImage`.

`myImage` and the object are two different things.  `myImage` merely points at a memory location.  It is not the object itself.

You can pass around objects without assigning them to variables, and you can assign one object to many variables.

Consider this:

```
UIImage *imageOne;
UIImage *imageTwo;

imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPhoto.jpg"];
imageTwo = imageOne;
```

The image wasn't copied.  There is only one object in existence.  Both variables point to it.

Now consider this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPhoto.jpg"]);
```

You didn't assign it to any variable.  But the object still existed, right?

Comment: That is eye opening. Thank you.

So one last question... what exactly is the object,  I always thought that the pointer was the object. For example..

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello"];


I thought that *myString would be the object.

Comment: The pointer is a pointer. The pointer points to the object. Two pointers can point to the same object. Got it?

Comment: Ohhhhh.. haha, Thank you. I love you guys. I got it now. That makes everything easier now.

Comment: `myString` is just a number telling iOS where in memory the object is.  That's what the asterisk signifies.  A lot of the time you can get away with thinking of it as "the object", but in reality, the object is just a block of data somewhere in memory, and you deal with pointers to it.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers guys. This helps me a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIImage`. Under the heading "Cached Image Loading Routines" and "Creating New Images" are some methods with a `+` where you might expect a `-`. This means that calling these methods is the same as calling `[[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];`, though some of them do more (as in custom initialization).

Lots of other Objective C objects have similar methods, for example, `NSArray` has a method `+(id)array` that creates and returns an empty array. Your main indicator here is the `+` instead of the `-`, but I always check the documentation to check how the initialization is handled and to make sure the object is autoreleased.

Comment: These are known as "convenience methods".  Cocoa has [very consistent conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html) for knowing the memory management rules for objects returned by Cocoa methods, so once you know the rules, checking the documentation for each method is unnecessary.  The `+` vs `-` indicates whether a method is a class method or an instance method, it isn't directly related to this issue.